# ifps/kubo upload always returns some error

Tags: go

```
p1, err := api.Object().Put(ctx, strings.NewReader(`{"Data":"YmFy"}`), options.Object.Pin(true), options.Object.DataType("base64"), options.Object.InputEnc("json"))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("1")
    panic(err)
}
```

the err :panic: Post "http://192.168.1.127:4001/api/v0/version?": net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response "\xdeJ\xd2\xf86\xcd\xf8]\t\x8a\x17\u0381\xadm\x7f$ݳ\v\xff\xe8\xaa&"